# Cómo hacer una buena traducción de "chickens coming home to roost"

Tags: traducción, modismos

En la vida de Malcolm X, se destaca la entrevista que entrega después del asesinato de J. F. Kennedy en la cual mencionó lo siguiente

> "*chickens coming home to roost* never did make me sad; they've always made me glad."

En varias traducciones en español de la frase *chickens coming home to roost* (en Encarta 98 o Wikipedia) se hace una traducción literal, que no da mucho sentido a la entrevista y sus posteriores consecuencias (fue censurado por sus organización). Decir que Las gallinas vuelven a dormir a casa... no suena a motivo de censura. Lo extraño es que en [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_chickens_come_home_to_roost) dan el dicho con origen español o turco, diciendo que las mentiras, como las gallinas, retornan a casa. Pero lo más importante sería adecuar este dicho o refrán para este caso... no sé si un 'cría cuervos...' o 'quien siembra vientos...' pero si pueden confirmar con otros ejemplos conocidos y (como extra) si se puede confirmar el origen español del mismo, mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Chickens coming home to roost* se refiere a la costumbre de las gallinas de volver por su cuenta al gallinero al terminar el día (*roost* implica "descansar" y también "posarse, instalarse en un lugar"). Si se busca una traducción no literal y que sea también un dicho o símil, "Cría cuervos y te sacarán los ojos" es en mi opinión mejor que "Quien siembra vientos cosecha tempestades", porque los cuervos son agentes libres y aves, para mejor, como las gallinas.

El problema al traducir el símil con otro símil en este caso es que en su entrevista Malcolm X hace un truco interesante de utilizar *chickens coming home to roost* al mismo tiempo como símil y como expresión literal: la frase completa fue

> “Being an old farm boy myself, chickens coming home to roost never did
>   make me sad; they’ve always made me glad.”

Es decir, que por haber vivido y trabajado en una granja, ver cómo las gallinas volvían a dormir al gallinero nunca fue algo que le desagradase, sino todo lo contrario. Se podría debatir si Malcolm X quiso de hecho regodearse con el asesinato de JFK o si más bien (y de manera muy polémica) quiso señalar que era natural y correcto que las acciones tienen consecuencias. Con nuestro dicho de los cuervos esto sería más difícil porque 1) en las granjas no se crían cuervos, 2) lo de que le sacan los ojos a la gente es un mito, 3) si de hecho le sacaran los ojos a la gente, esto no alegraría a quien lo viese. O sea que nuestro Malcolm X traducido no podría nunca emplear nuestro símil de los cuervos de la misma manera que lo hizo con el de las gallinas.

Comment: @walen Sí, pero a cambio pierde el parecido con la expresión original en varios puntos.

Comment: @walen I think your first suggestion is a perfect fit for the phrase "As ye sow, so shall ye reap". Interesting you have that in Spanish but not the chickens.

Comment: @walen ¿y qué tal "quien siembra vientos, recoge tempestades"?

Comment: @walen uy, no lo había visto, aunque no sé pero a mí me parece mejor...

Comment: En efecto, también eso que señala @walen. Las gallinas siguen siendo las mismas, las dificultades no se multiplican, simplemente lo que hiciste termina volviéndote.

Comment: en tal caso @pablodf76, ¿considerás que la mejor opción es dejarlo en traducción literal aunque pierda ese *toque literario* que causa un refrán o un dicho similar?

Comment: @VeAqui No sé, probablemente sí, literal y con una breve explicación sería mejor.

Answer (score 3):

En el sitio web `www.malcolm-x.org` se puede leer [lo siguiente](http://www.malcolm-x.org/speeches/spc_120463.htm) referente a un discurso que dio tras la muerte de Kennedy, titulado *God's Judgement of White America (The Chickens Come Home to Roost)*:

> This speech is sometimes called "*The Chickens Come Home To Roost*," because of an answer Malcolm X gave in response to a question following the speech. The question concerned the late President John Kennedy. It was Malcolm X's answer, that the Presidents death was a case of "chickens coming home to roost" -- that the violence that Kennedy had failed to stop had come back to him, this resulted in the Elijah Muhammad silencing him. Malcolm X left the Nation of Islam a short time later.

También he encontrado un texto que dice [lo siguiente](https://books.google.es/books?id=lk_KDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT234&lpg=PT234&dq=las%20gallinas%20siempre%20vuelven%20al%20gallinero&source=bl&ots=AQu9wTu7Rx&sig=pc6FnLanzeLYb0CGKknQUgfzexQ&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtx9XixYfZAhUKXhQKHaGeDf8Q6AEISjAH#v=onepage&q=las%20gallinas%20siempre%20vuelven%20al%20gallinero&f=false):

> En ese punto, Malcolm perdió los estribos y llegó a afirmar que aquel homicidio venía a significar que las maldiciones siempre vuelven contra quienes las han lanzado, "igual que las gallinas vuelven al gallinero". La Norteamérica blanca, afirmó, llevaba años utilizando todos sus recursos con el propósito de reducir a los negros [...] Ahora, todos esos esfuerzos se estaban volviendo en contra de sus líderes. El público, en Harlem, manifestó su alborozo, y Malcolm, acallando los aplausos, añadió que él se había criado en el campo y que "nunca me puse triste al ver que las gallinas vuelven al gallinero. Al contrario. Es algo que siempre me ha alegrado".

Por tanto, la frase que mencionas en tu pregunta es una referencia a una frase anterior que queda explicada en su momento. De hecho, cuando vuelve a hacer referencia a las gallinas dice que es de campo, por lo que en ese instante está hablando de las gallinas de verdad, y por tanto esa frase tiene sentido traducida literalmente.

No creo que sea una frase hecha ni que proceda de otros idiomas. Simplemente estaba usando una analogía para el concepto del karma y de que las cosas que uno hace se pueden volver contra uno mismo.

Comment: gracias por ayudarme con la investigación que se supone debe realizar uno cuando plantea la pregunta, de cual es el contexto de la frase pues solo tenía parte de la respuesta al NYTimes y la posterior sanción de la nación del Islam. No sabía que lo había dicho en público ni la referencia a la *Norteamérica blanca* y otros tantos temas, creía que era una entrevista personal